# PHP - Logging strange behaviour

Tags: php, logging

I have two php files.

```
  <?php


register_shutdown_function("shutdownHandler");
require_once ('apache-log4php-2.3.0/src/main/php/Logger.php');
Logger::configure($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/front-page/lib/logger.xml');

function shutdownHandler()
{
    $lasterror = error_get_last();
    switch ($lasterror['type'])
    {
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_CORE_ERROR:
        case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
        case E_CORE_WARNING:
        case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
        case E_PARSE:
            $error = "[SHUTDOWN] :" . $lasterror['type'] . " | msg:" . 
                        $lasterror['message'] . " | file:" . $lasterror['file'] . " | ln:" . $lasterror['line'];
            $log = Logger::getLogger('myLogger');
            $log->info($error);
    }
}

?>
```

I referred this error handling at SO.

I have another page

```
<?php
  include('myPage.php')
?>
```

I have modified `php.ini` so that first php will be prepended to all php.

I want to do error handling for my web page. I just added something as follows in my second page

```
 <?php
  require 'myPageXYZ.php';
 ?>
```

My file is missing.[Because I have misspelled] So `require` will throw fatal error. I am logging it in a file with `log4php`. But unfortunately logging is not working.

I debugged the code. It goes to the case statement and executes but log file is not created.

I just modified as follows in my second php file

```
 <?php
   $log = Logger::getLogger('myLogger');
   $log->info("ok");
   include('myPage.php')
 ?>
```

IT WORKS. It creates the file and logs `ok` and `error statement` also. So I guess there is nothing wrong with my `log4php` properties. Please let me know what I am missing. Am I missing anything in between two php files? Like scope or something.

**EDIT:**

LOG4PHP xml file:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
<appender name="myAppender" class="LoggerAppenderFile">
    <param name="file" value="myLog.log" />
</appender>

<appender name="myConsoleAppender" class="LoggerAppenderConsole" />
<logger name="myLogger">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender_ref ref="myAppender" />
 </logger>
</configuration>
```

Comment: And what happens in the logger? You said it goes there. Check paths and permissions there.

Comment: @awons Just consider my second case. I have added dummy logger. Both files resides at same place. Permission may not be the issue.

Comment: You said that in the second case the code goes into the logger. So it means something wrong happens there. We can't see the code of it so it is hard to say what is happening there. Try with to go step by step and see what is happening there.

Comment: @awons I debugged step by step. In both cases control reaches correct locations.[I mean error handler] But logger is working only in the second case. This is my complete code to describe error. I will add my log4php properties also.